# Name for genderless/male-and-female-all-in-one connectors for chaining PCBs?

Tags: pcb, connector

I'm looking to make a modular system which can be expanded left or right, as well as fed from either left or right side, depending on customer location and available space.

Having a standard outlet in a female connector and input in a male counterpart will make it less flexible since it has a given direction and/or you need to flip the board upside down. One can cheat using two connectors like this simplified example (pardon my MS paint skills):

[image]

But is there no magic search term for a connector which has one male and one female part in the same connector to achive the same thing? My google-fu is failing me here.

Comment: A beautiful rendition. Is the reason behind this so that only one item appears on the BoM (used in two places on each board)?

Comment: Hermaphroditic connectors.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks! :-) Pretty much yes. Twice the volume on one just item is better than original volume on two different parts.

Comment: Hermaphroditic is the term. Like https://www.newark.com/samtec/lst-128-07-g-d/socket-2-54mm-56-position/dp/85T5436?CMP=AFC-ECIA

Comment: @DKNguyen BINGO! Can you make it an answer?

Comment: Nice paint skills.

Comment: You're saying the board has a direction and you need to be able to install it facing left or facing right, regardless of which direction the adjacent boards are facing?

Comment: Is gender the right word? After all, you're asking about their physical attributes, not how they identify. :)

Comment: You could _potentially_ use something like [back-to-back pins] to connect two boards with sockets on each.

Comment: Another often-used option is only using female connectors on the boards and requiring a male-male connector between them for connection. Would this be acceptable?

Comment: @Acccumulation But then you can't use the term gender bender for something that converts male to female. You would need...more graphic terms that don't roll off the tongue as nicely.

Comment: @τεκ Not more than a front face towards the customer. I added up and down in the image to make it more generic or clear, but in my application I could probably just add silkscreen text both right side up and upside down to make it work in either. My goal is still to have just one module and expansion to both right and left side needs to be possible.

Comment: @winny In that case, you could have all the male connectors on the left and female connectors on the right. Signals can go either way. Expanding to the left would mean plugging the female connector of the new board to the leftmost male connector of the chain, and to the right would mean plugging the male connector of the new board into the rightmost female connector of the chain.

Comment: @τεκ That would take two separate infeed connectors, one for male and one for female.

Comment: @winny Why? Wouldn't just one regular connector on each side work? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujun8.png

Comment: Infeed can come from either side. If left in your image, I need a female connector for it. If right, I need a male connector. Too complicated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hermaphroditic connectors. Most I see are vertically hermaphroditic though and you seem to want horizontally hermaphroditic. Note you can turn the board upside down and plug it in the wrong way, though you can do that in your original image too.

With regards to reducing BOM count, most hermaphroditic connectors seem to be vertically hermaproditic (like interlocking L-shapes that sit vertically on the board). In this case, unless it is truly an edge-mounted version, would need two different versions (right side up and upside down) to mount on the same side of the PCB in order to not produce a stair-case of PCBs when chaining boards together. So you would still need two parts on your BOM.

However, if you can find horizontally hermaphroditic connectors (like interlocking L-shapes that lay flat in the plane of the board) that basically look like single-part versions of your male/female connectors then the stair case is not an issue with just a single part number.

Comment: "I do not think you'll find this unless it is an edge mounted version" – I don't understand the point you're making here. Isn't it quite clear that the asker *does* want an edge mounted version? There are certainly horizontally hermaphroditic edge-mounted connectors for exactly this purpose, aren't there?

Comment: @TannerSwett When I mean "truly edge mounted", I do not mean "right angle but sits on either the top layer or the bottom layer of the board". I mean it actually mounts on the edge of the board like how some SMA connectors straddle the board or some USB connectors sit in a slot cut into the PCB so just as much of the connector sits above the board as it does below it. Because if it doesn't and you use it to chain a bunch of identical boards together, the boards form a stair case.

Comment: @TannerSwett Actually, I think I understand your point. It is that any right-angle hermaphroditic connector would introduce a stair case even if it's just two PCBs. So there in order not to there would have be two versions of the right angle connectors and I just looked at the Samtec LSHM and there are: A right angle and reverse-right angle connector.

Comment: I think I understand your point now. It sounds like you're interpreting the question as requiring the system to work for **any** 180 degree rotation of the second board, including flipping the second board so that the front of the second board lines up with the back of the first board and the back of the second lines up with the front of the first. I'm interpreting the question as only requiring the system to work for that 180 degree rotation which leaves the front and the back facing the same way.

Comment: @TannerSwett Yeah. From the pictures it seems that the OP wants either end of the PCB to be able into either end of the next PCB. No front or back for the train car, so to speak. Of course, that also allows you to flip the board upside down and connect it the wrong way which can't happen in your "one-way" method which does not need hermaphroditic connectors at all: just have horizontally keyed male connectors on one end and female connectors on the other end.

Comment: In any case, if my interpretation is correct, then just simply having a hermaphroditic connector on the front face of the board, one on each edge of the board, will do the trick perfectly. If your interpretation is correct, then you'll need to have two hermaphroditic connectors (one on the front face and one on the back face), but those two connectors can be identical. Unless, as you mentioned, you use some fancy one that's centered on the edge and allows for a 180 degree axial rotation.

Comment: @TannerSwett Yes. I guess I just didn't see a point for having hermaphroditic connectors (specifically vertically hermaphroditic which most seem to be) in your one-way method so I subconsciously ruled it out. It wouldn't help the BOM count either way since you still need two different connectors on each side either male or female, or hermaphroditic right-side up and upside down to not have a stair case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "your 'one-way' method"; I haven't suggested any methods in which the two opposite edges of the board are not interchangeable. Just as you described, I've been talking about having "either end of the PCB to be able to plug into either end of the next PCB" this entire time. And in any case, my original idea involved using a total of two connectors on each board: both on the front face, one on each of the two short edges (assuming that the boards connect short-edge-to-short-edge).

Comment: @Tanner I think the issue might be that there are horizontally hermaphroditic connectors and vertically hermaphroditic connectors. I keep thinking about vertically hermaphroditic since that is what most seem to be and those produce a stair case without two different versions: right side up and upside down. I think you may be talking about horizontally hermaphroditic which doesn't have this problem. So yeah, if the OP finds horizontally hermaphoriditc then just one part number will suffice.

Comment: @TannerSwett In any case, even if I may have misunderstood what you said, it has helped clarify a number of alternative cases that I missed in my answer. I think the root cause was the particular axis of rotation we're talking about since we're not using pictures. I think we're actually talking about the same orientations (my one-way misinterpretation aside). Except I misinterpreted yours as one-way and you might have misinterpreted my way as also allowing the boards to be turned upside down (at least I think you may have, I am not sure but plugging in upside down was not my intention).

Answer (score 1):

Samtec has the LSXX parts, other vendors have similar horizontal connectors. You should take into account all the creative ways your users can connect the boards.

Comment: Yeah, the Samtec LSHM is what I would have used.